# Multiple Match queries in one query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following records in my neo4j database

```
(:A)-[:B]->(:C)-[:D]->(:E)

(:C)-[:D]->(:E)
```

I want to get all the C Nodes and all the relations and related Nodes. If I do the query

```
Match (p:A)-[o:B]->(i:C)-[u:D]->(y:E) 
Return p,o,i,u,y
```

I get the first to match if I do

```
Match (i:C)-[u:D]->(y:E) 
Return i,u,y
```

I get the second to match.

But I want both of them in one query. How do I do that?

Comment: did you try optional match?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to UNION the queries, and pad unused variables with null (because all cyphers UNION'ed must have the same return columns

```
Match (p:A)-[o:B]->(i:C)-[u:D]->(y:E) 
Return p,o,i,u,y
UNION
Match (i:C)-[u:D]->(y:E) 
Return NULL as p, NULL as o,i,u,y
```

In your example though, the second match actually matches the last half of the first chain as well, so maybe you actually want something more direct like...

```
MATCH (c:C)
OPTIONAL MATCH (connected)
WHERE (c)-[*..20]-(connected)
RETURN c, COLLECT(connected) as connected
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're being a bit too specific in your query. If you just need, for all :C nodes, the connected nodes and relationships, then this should work:

```
MATCH (c:C)-[r]-(n)
RETURN c, r, n
```